# Laravel prevent deletion if child table is > 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I using Laravel 5.8 and i have this situation. I want to prevent the deletion of a category if it has products in it. This is what i have so far

Category.php

```php
  public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
  }

  protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($category) {
         if ($category->products()->count() > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    });

  }
```

CategoriesController.php

```php
    public function destroy($id) {
      $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
      $delete_status = $category->delete();

      if($delete_status == 1) {
        return redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('success','Deleted Sucesfully');
      } else {
        return redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('error','Cant delete bacause it has products in it');
      }
    }
```

it works so far but i feel it's a little sketchy. The $delete_status variable return 1 if the category doesn't have any products but it returns nothing if the category has products in it, also that why i use an if/else and not an if/elseif.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It returns false if there's products, not nothing. So all you have to do is `if($delete_status)`, since it will be either false, or a truthy value.

Comment: I don't know if this is 'better' or not, but you could add a fk constraint on the DB and catch an exception when trying to delete. This way the DB guarantees the integrity, not the code.

Comment: The only sane and acceptable way of doing this is what @Bryan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**Category.php**

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

**CategoriesController.php**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    if (empty($category))
        abort(404);
    if($category->products->count())
        redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('error',"Can't delete because it has products in it");

    try {
        $category->delete();
        redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('success', 'Category has been deleted successfully');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('error','Something went wrong please try again later!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you use only one return. This. Mean that when enter to if which inside deleting function then return anthing otherwise nothing. Maybe you must else statement return anything.